# delphi можно ли вызывать DeallocateHWnd во 2м потоке если AllocateHWnd был создан в 1м

Tags: delphi

```
FHandleApp := AllocateHWnd(WndProcApplication);
```

Можно ли вызвать в другом потоке DeallocateHWnd
Спрашиваю т.к пытаюсь найти баг в старой проге. Она иногда сама закрывается
как будто переполнение стека произошло

```
DeallocateHWnd(FHandleApp);
```

Comment: Подключите `FastMM memory manager`, он поможет найти множество проблем, связанных с переполнением памяти, обращением к удаленным объектам и так далее. `DeallocateHWnd` не является потокобезопасной, но если не брать случай конкурентного обращения к одному Hwnd - то это допустимо. Поэтому FastMM и вперед, на поиски приключений

Comment: Насколько я помню, AllocateHWnd() сама по себе [не потокобезопасная](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820294/how-can-i-make-allocatehwnd-threadsafe).

Comment: @kami, она там к глобальной переменной обращается и класс окна регистрирует/удаляет, так что даже с разными HWND они не потокобезопасные.

Answer (score 0):

По правилам хорошего тона и избежания подводных камней, рекомендую освобождать память из того потока, в котором память выделялась.В первом потоке выделили память, из другого потока вы можете уведомить первый поток, что пора освободить память. Реализовать это можно с помощью Callback или какого либо метода переданного в второй поток